# How to make an input element take up all available vertical space?

Tags: html, css, input, height

I'm currently working on a calculator in HTML and have made a form to input various numbers. The form is located in a div that's a sidebar, and I've made a div for each row holding an input and label. However, the input elements are left with a lot of space above them, as well as the borders as they're attached to the input elements. How could I allow the inputs to take up all available vertical space? [Picture of extra space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJIiu.png)

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #272640;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #3E1F47;
}

#sidebarCentered {
}

.siderow {
  background-color: #312244;
  border-top: 1px solid #3E1F47;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50% text-align:center;
  font-family: monaco;
}

.siderow label {}

.siderow input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #312244;
  border: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #5A5766;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarbuttons {
  background-color: #312244;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.sidebarbuttons input {
  background-color: #312244;
  font-family: monaco;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 45%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #3E1F47;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.sidebarbuttons input:hover {
  background-color: #272640;
  color: #272640;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

#centermenu {
  background-color: #212F45;
  color: #EDFFEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5A5766;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <form id="sidebarCentered">
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="balance">Balance:</label>
      <input type="number" name="balance" value=500>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="monthly">Monthly <br> contribution:</label>
      <input type="number" name="monthly" value=0>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="nummonths">Number of <br> Months:</label>
      <input type="number" name="nummonths" value=12>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow" style="border-bottom:1px solid #3E1F47;">
      <label for="ror">Monthly Rate <br> of Return:</label>
      <input type="number" name="ror" value=1>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarbuttons">
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" style="float:left;">
      <input type="button" value="Quit" style="float:right;">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give .siderow padding of 0 and add a height to .siderow input and .siderow label.

Next, delete those br tags and add flex to .siderow label so it can be vertically aligned in the middle. Also, don't use inline css.

In all, you will have this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <form id="sidebarCentered">
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="balance">Balance:</label>
      <input type="number" name="balance" value=500>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="monthly">Monthly contribution:</label>
      <input type="number" name="monthly" value=0>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="nummonths">Number of Months:</label>
      <input type="number" name="nummonths" value=12>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="ror">Monthly Rate of Return:</label>
      <input type="number" name="ror" value=1>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarbuttons">
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" style="float:left;">
      <input type="button" value="Quit" style="float:right;">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.sidebar {
  background-color: #272640;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #5A5766;
}

#sidebarCentered {
}

.siderow {
  border-top: 1px solid #5A5766;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: monaco;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.siderow:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

.siderow:nth-child(4) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5A5766;
}

.siderow label {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.siderow input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #272640;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #5A5766;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
}

.sidebarbuttons {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.sidebarbuttons input {
  background-color: #888;
  font-family: monaco;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 45%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #5A5766;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.sidebarbuttons input:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #272640;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

#centermenu {
  background-color: #212F45;
  color: #EDFFEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5A5766;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Link to Fiddle for reference https://jsfiddle.net/kavyw86d/

Answer (score 0):

That space is caused by padding of 10px in `.siderow`. I changed the padding to `0 10px` which sets top and bottom padding to zero and left/right to 10px. I also added `min-width: 200px;` to `.sidebar` for clarity. You may want to change that. Extra vertical space has been removed.

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #272640;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #3E1F47;
}

#sidebarCentered {
}

.siderow {
  background-color: #312244;
  border-top: 1px solid #3E1F47;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px; /* changed here */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50% text-align:center;
  font-family: monaco;
}

.siderow label {}

.siderow input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #312244;
  border: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid #5A5766;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebarbuttons {
  background-color: #312244;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.sidebarbuttons input {
  background-color: #312244;
  font-family: monaco;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 45%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #3E1F47;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.sidebarbuttons input:hover {
  background-color: #272640;
  color: #272640;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

#centermenu {
  background-color: #212F45;
  color: #EDFFEC;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5A5766;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <form id="sidebarCentered">
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="balance">Balance:</label>
      <input type="number" name="balance" value=500>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="monthly">Monthly <br> contribution:</label>
      <input type="number" name="monthly" value=0>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow">
      <label for="nummonths">Number of <br> Months:</label>
      <input type="number" name="nummonths" value=12>
    </div>
    <div class="siderow" style="border-bottom:1px solid #3E1F47;">
      <label for="ror">Monthly Rate <br> of Return:</label>
      <input type="number" name="ror" value=1>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarbuttons">
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" style="float:left;">
      <input type="button" value="Quit" style="float:right;">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```